# How to access unknown class methods

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, inner-classes

I am currently coding in Java language, but I am facing a situation where I have

```
class A{
static class A1{
    void same1(){}
    int same2(){}
}
static class A2{
void same1(){}
    int same2(){}
}
}
```

I used generics to store the object in a map, where I store description and the objects as A1 and A2

```
Map<String, Object> mapObject=new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Is it possible to access methods inside the inner classes if I retrieve from the map the classname.
Currently, I am able to get class name by `mapObject.get(key).getClass()`.
Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.Thank You.

Comment: `mapObject.get(key).getClass().getDeclaredMethods()`

Comment: In Java only Objects get capitalized. `class`, `static`, `void` and `int` should all be lowercase. `String`, `Object` and `(Hash)Map` are all Objects, so they are the only words that are supposed to be capitalized.

Comment: @Shahzeb Thanks a million, I am able to get the methods, Could you help me a bit more.Actually I need to pass arguments as well.How can I pass it to method object?

Comment: @TotZam Yes I am sorry about that, I just wanted to gave an example, so created in a document and autocorrect has done its job. :(

Comment: @Vin99999: The Java API that enables you to explore the classes, interfaces, methods, and fields that you will not have known at compile-time for your own program is called the Reflection API.   There is an excellent Reflection tutorial available at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code to see how to work with methods and invoking via reflections as you asked in your comments. Please note this code is very adhoc and what you are trying to do does not seem right. Hardly ever if at all does one need to call methods like this. If you could in a new question ask what problem is it that you are trying to solve you might see other better approaches.

```
package com.so;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Sample {
    private Map<String,Foo> mapObject = new HashMap<String,Foo>();

    public Sample(){
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        mapObject.put("key", foo);
    }

    public void callMethods() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
        Method[] methods = mapObject.get("key").getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        Object objectString = new String();
        objectString = "Hello";
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("printThisString")){
                method.invoke(mapObject.get("key"), objectString)   ;
            }

         }

    }

    public static void main(String...args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.callMethods();
    }

}

class Foo {
    public void printThisString(String param){
        System.out.println(param);
    }
}
```